# Is it possible with OOP in Java to automatically call a method when an object's variable turns into specific condition?

Tags: java, oop

I'm sorry in advanced if this was a silly question, just understand the fact that I'm a beginner, so please don't be too harsh with me if I'm asking something like this.

I am practicing to work my way with understanding how object's attributes works with each other (OOP)
I tried to mimick a game scenario as my practice idea, I initialised HPs and attack values in each object creation, I have created an attack method which simply just decrements the HP of the attacked entity, what I want to accomplish is that every time the HP of the attacked entity turns zero or less, it will automatically reassign its value to 0, and prints a message "An enemy was terminated"

**This was the class**
`

```
public class Character {
    
    int HP;
    int ATK;
    
}

class Player extends Character {
    
    // default values
    public Player() {
        HP = 100;
        ATK = 40;
    }
    
    // attack method
    public void attack(Enemy a) {
        a.HP -= this.ATK;
    }
    
    
}

class Enemy extends Character {
    
    public Enemy() {
        HP = 50;
        ATK = 10;
    }
    
    public void attack(Player a) {
        a.HP -= this.ATK;
    }
}
```

`

**Using it in main method:**

`

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // instantiation
        Player p = new Player();
        Enemy e1 = new Enemy();
        
                
        System.out.println("Player's HP: " + p.HP); // 100
        System.out.println("Enemy's HP: " + e1.HP + "\n"); // 50
    
        
        System.out.println("*Enemy attacking Player*");
        e1.attack(p);
        System.out.println("Player's HP: " + p.HP); // 90
        System.out.println("Enemy's HP: " + e1.HP + "\n"); // 50

        System.out.println("*Player attacking Enemy*");
        p.attack(e1);
        System.out.println("Player's HP: " + p.HP); // 90
        System.out.println("Enemy's HP: " + e1.HP + "\n"); // 10

        p.attack(e1); 
        /* when I did it again, it will turn enemy's HP to -30 */
    }
}
```

`

And as I've said in the previous sentence, what I want to accomplish is instead of letting that value to continue decrementing to the negative numbers, I want its value to set as zero and print a message about the termination of the enemy.

I have no idea if this was a silly way of practicing (I apologize in advanced)

I have tried doing this but it feels wrong.
(and it didn't worked)
Edit: The value wasn't affected by the if statement, the same thing still occurs within the HP of the enemy even if its value is less than or equal to 0.
`

```
class Player extends Character {
    
    // default values
    public Player() {
        HP = 100;
        ATK = 40;
    }
    
    // attack method
        public void attack(Enemy a) {
                if (!(this.HP <= 0)) {
                a.HP -= this.ATK;
        } else {
            a.HP = 0;
            System.out.println("An enemy was terminated.");
        }
    }
    
}
```

`

I also tried doing that with constructor but I felt that was wrong as well because constructors works for initializing objects and not for waiting for a specific condition.

I'm very sorry if this question is silly, I swear I have no idea if you would laugh at this thinking "why would you ever going to program a thing like that?", I'm just a beginner, so please bear with me.

Comment: You say what you tried feels wrong and didn't work, but you don't say why it feels wrong and in what way exactly it didn't work. Can you please add those details to your question? "It didn't work" is never useful, you should always explain in detail what you mean when you say "didn't work", because it could be many things: output differs from what you expect, an exception is thrown, etc. That said, I recommend that you reread your code carefully: you want to decrease the enemy's HP to a minimum of 0, but your if/else checks the player's HP to decide what to do, not the enemy's.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, what I mean by that is that nothing happens at all, the output still prints the same thing, instead of seeing the conditional statement to modify the attributes' value based on the condition, it does nothing, it kept on decrementing the number til negative values.

Comment: Yeah, I was editing my comment. That happens because your condition checks the player's HP, not the enemy's.

Comment: Thank you very much! I haven't realised that at first glance.

Comment: "Is it possible to automatically call a method?" No, you must always write out the method call yourself. There is nothing automatic about computer programming.

Comment: With that said, check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Thanks for such tip, but what I meant is not really automatically call a method without writing anything that calls that method, but rather perform a method under specific condition (such as declaring an if statement, and writing a method inside that was only called ones the given condition returns true. I'm sorry if I haven't clarified this initially), and thanks for the second tip!